# Delete records if an updated record exists

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have an access database containing records pulled in from csv files which are published daily.  From time to time, an existing record is updated.  My current database is of the form

```
... ID ... Date on which the csv file was created
     1             26/05/2013
     1             27/05/2013
     2             27/05/2013
     3             26/05/2013
etc.
```

How do I get Access to delete the older record in VBA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `DMax` expression which returns the most recent `creation_date` for each `ID`.

```vb
DMax("creation_date", "YourTable", "ID=" & <current ID>)
```

Then use that expression in a `SELECT` query to identify the rows which you want discarded.

```vb
SELECT
    y.ID,
    y.creation_date,
    DMax("creation_date", "YourTable", "ID=" & y.ID)
FROM YourTable AS y;
```

Once you have the `SELECT` query working correctly, use its working `DMax` expression in a `DELETE` query.

```vb
DELETE FROM YourTable
WHERE creation_date < DMax("creation_date", "YourTable", "ID=" & [ID]);
```

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean by "y".  What is that referring to, my table?

Comment: I used "y" as an alias for the table name.  You don't actually need it in that query.  However I often use a short alias because the Access query designer otherwise wants to qualify each field with the full table name ... ie `YourTable.creation_date`.

Comment: In the line `DMax("creation_date", "YourTable", "ID=" & y.ID)`, should that not be `DMax("creation_date", "YourTable", "ID=" & <current ID>)"` ?

Comment: In the query, `y.ID` is the `ID` value of the current row, which is what I meant with `<current ID>` in the other `DMax` expression.  However, I wonder if I've misunderstood your comment.  (?)

Comment: Perfect, I got it all working.  Thanks for dumbing it down for me!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a `delete` with a `where` clause?

```
delete from t
     where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id > t.id)
```

I'm not absolutely positive that Access lets you select and delete from the same table.  If not, then you can put the ids in a temporary table and delete using that.

To be honest, I'm not thrilled with the idea of deleting the records directly.  Try creating a new table with the records you want:

```
select *
from t
where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id > t.id)
```

This should work, assuming you have an index on `id`.  Then delete the original table and replace it with the new one *after* you have validated that the right records are in it.

Comment: How would you deal with a large ID range though?  The IDs actually go from ~100000000 - ~500000000, with over 1 million records in some tables.  Would I just loop through each one inserting the number after the select statement?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete all the older records with duplicate IDs at once, you can just execute this SQL.

However, it will require that you have a primary or unique field. I added a field called **RecID** that's just an autonumber field.

```
strSQL = ""
strSQL = strSQL & "DELETE " & vbCrLf
strSQL = strSQL & "  t.recid, " & vbCrLf
strSQL = strSQL & "  t.* " & vbCrLf
strSQL = strSQL & "FROM t " & vbCrLf
strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE  t.recid NOT IN (SELECT Last(t.recid) AS LastOfRecID " & vbCrLf
strSQL = strSQL & "                       FROM   t " & vbCrLf
strSQL = strSQL & "                       GROUP  BY t.id)"
```

Then you just do a `Currentdb.Execute(strSQL)`